# Why does Google keep rejecting my update for my game?

Tags: google-play, advertisements, unity-ads

I'm trying to push an update to my game that is on the Google Play Store. I've submitted the update over 4 times and Google keeps rejecting it due to the type of ads that are being displayed. I'm using Unity Ads and I've disabled all ads that would be inappropriate such as gambling, dating, 18+..etc.

The annoying part is that I have the game already on the store and I never disabled any of the ads or filtered the ads. Unity Ads are an approved service by Google. Is there something that I am missing? I also have a privacy policy in place as well? Is there something that I could do to keep it from getting rejected? How does Google test games or apps for ad content?!

**Update** So I've tired submitting the update over 8+ times and it's still being rejected. I've disabled the banner ads and I've changed the ads to not show ads rated for 5+. I'm at a loss for why it's being rejected. I've emailed Google over it and they just send me the same information they sent when it was rejected the first time. Still no answer..

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDlj1.jpg)!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHGPi.jpg)

Comment: Can you walk us through how you've configured your Unity ads, so we can try to reproduce the problem? The full text of the error message could help too.

Comment: @DMGregory I've added a picture showing how I have my ads filtered and set up. I haven't changed anything within the game itself. Only with Unity Dashboard > Operate > Monetization > Ad Filtering

Comment: sometimes google changes its policies. sometimes you simply updates your game now you cant.  check your campaigns and ages in your advertisment panel can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after getting an email from Google, I figured out that once your APK is rejected, you have to reupload a new APK. I was just trying to adjust the ad content in unity dashboard. So after adjusting the ad content and reuploading a new APK, it was accepted. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you target for kids or are on the family list you need  to exclude anything 13+ or you won't be in compliance. If you swap that and submit you should pass

Comment: I'm going to try what you mentioned. I just submitted the update again and I'll post an update with the result. But why would they not deny this game or my first game when I first submitted it? Because when I submitted my first 2 games, I have no restrictions and all ads are being shown?

Comment: The policy changed is the reasoning behind why. They did that whole privacy policy thing and also the advertising. Some games submitted before certain date they will be up but over time will have to update to new policy before they get taken down.

Comment: So the game update was rejected again with for the same thing. I excluded any ads for ages 13+ and it still got rejected. When I filter the ads, does this filter banner ads too? I have a banner ad on the bottom of the screen. Or just ads that are played to earn more in game currency? (That's how players watch ads in my game)

Comment: Can you show the error or report or reason(s) they gave you?

Comment: I don't know what or where the error report would be, but I'll update the question with a screenshot of the email they sent.

Comment: it must be the banner that is breaking the rules then. That's my best guess. try taking that out and submitting Then if that passes go from there on adjusting the banner. Who is the banner ad through? Or is that also unity ads in that case I am at a loss if you only target below 13+ w their ads